# Fatal Error: Added field has duplicate identifier(): APT_TRinput0Rec99 (ALR_DATIBAS3.FilterFieldError)

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I have a job with 181 columns, I'm getting this error while compiling on a transformer before a funnel.

*Fatal Error: Added field has duplicate identifier(): APT_TRinput0Rec99 (ALR_DATIBAS3.FilterFieldError)*

The transformer has 181 constraints and nothing special, what can i try to solve it?

Comment: Are you using Runtime column Propagation? Maybe this is turned on...

Comment: I just checked in the job properties and inside the stage properties, is turned off